# Why different error messages while using identifiers?

Tags: python, jupyter, identifier

Since both the code snippets are starting with a number, it should give same error message. Why are different error messages are given in the two lines?

```
12_abc=12
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

```
12abc=12
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: python ints can be written with `_` to allow for easier reading of longer numbers. For example you can write `1_000_000` and thats a valid int. In your first example since you have a num followed by an underscore then a letter you get the invalid decimal literal as the python interpreter sees this as a parsing error of an integer. In your second example since you dont have the underscore its just a syntax error

Comment: Please include code and errors in your question as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Also note that python variable names can't begin with numbers

Answer (score 1):

the problem is by your way of declaring the variables . You can not declare a variable starting with a number, it can contain number , so python is not made to understand such variable name . You could name it anything else ...
If the problem was more clarified i could help you with the problem.